# What is the meaning of the woman and the baby in the film Stigmata?

Tags: symbols, christian, stigmata

In the 1999 film *Stigmata*, protagonist Frankie Paige looks out of the window and sees a weeping woman holding a baby. The woman lets the baby fall on the street which causes Frankie to run outside to try to save the baby, realizing neither the baby nor the woman are there as if they had been an illusion. As the movie doesn't elaborate any further on what exactly that scene means, does anyone have an idea or do we have a statement from the filmmakers on it? What would the symbolism of the woman with the baby mean (concerning Frankie)?

One may think of the Blessed Virgin Mary and Jesus, but the woman in Frankie's vision had blond hair, and I'm unsure why Frankie would have a vision of the baby falling.